# Pass js parameter value in database using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" onclick="myFunction('Overall rating:',5)" name="rating" value="5" />
<label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" onclick="myFunction('Overall rating:',4)" name="rating" value="4" />
<label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" onclick="myFunction('Overall rating:',3)" name="rating" value="3" />
<label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" onclick="myFunction('Overall rating:',2)" name="rating" value="2" />
<label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" onclick="myFunction('Overall rating:',1)" name="rating" value="1" />
<label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
<font  size="4"color="#ffffff">Overall rating:</font>
```

How do I pass js parameter value in database using php?

Comment: I don't understand anything, what do you want?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried to get this working?

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(x, y) {
 alert (x);
 $.post('rating.php',{'category':x,'rating':y},function(d){
  alert('hello'+d);
 })

 
}

Comment: i have a html code where i create a onclick function and pass 2 perameter and get it on js faction i need to pass these perameter value php that will help me to insert into database

Answer (score 0):

By using ajax

```
function myFunction(yourString, value) {
    $.get('updatePage.php', { 'yourkeyString': yourString, 'yourValue': value }, function (d) { alert('Hello from PHP: ' + d); });
}
```

Can check this answer also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/712378/6124249

Answer (score 0):

`Onchange()` of radio button call an ajax function, which will store your response in database.