# Updating Database Using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hopefully this will be the last question I need to ask about this..lol.. I cant be too far of the working solution(hopefully..lol). In reference to this question:

[Pass data to database using javascript Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712355/pass-data-to-database-using-javascript-onclick)

I am trying to pass a value to the database using javascript. Below is the code i am using. And just for visual aid, Ive included a screenshot of what this outputs. Hopefully it will help to explain what im trying to achieve also. The problem im having is the javascript "Vote" link pretty much does nothing...lol... u click it, and nothing happens. Preferably i would like the links text to simply change to "You Voted!" once the link has been clicked, and data sent/recieved, but an alert will be fine, as long as i can get this to work and update the database.

Thanks everyone:)

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['score'])) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO score (score_count) VALUES ($_POST[score])");
    }               $user_id = uid();
                $m = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_user_id1 = '$user_id' AND friend_status != '0' LIMIT 15");
                while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($m))
                {
                        $fid = $t[friend_user_id2];
                        $f = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_status != '' AND user_status_date != '0' AND user_id = '$fid' ORDER BY user_status_date ASC LIMIT 15") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($f))
                        {
    $date = parse_date($rows[user_status_date]);
                                echo "<div style='margin: 5px;'><table><tr><td valign='top' style='width:55px;'><a href='page.php?id=$rows[user_username]'>";
                                _photo($rows[user_id]);
                                echo '</a></td><td valign="top"> <a href="page.php?id='.$rows[user_username].'" class="blue"><b>'.$rows[user_username].'</b></a> - <span style="font-size:7pt;">'.$date.'</span><span style="font-size:7pt;"> - <a href="javascript:(void);" onclick="updateScore(this, correct)" class="blue">Vote</a></span>
    <br />'.$rows[user_status].'</td><td valign="top"></td></tr></table></div>';
                        }
                }
     ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateScore(answer, correct) {
      if (answer == correct) {
    $.get('index.php', {'score': '1'}, function(d) {
        alert('Vote Accepted: ' + d);
    });

      }
    }

    </script>
```

Outputs:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a7185475b8.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a7185475b8.png)

Comment: Well, I don't know if I'd label my first comment spiteful but I apologize.  My agenda is still intact.  You have the opportunity to craft your question and not litter it with "lol's" conveying a sense in triviality.  I'm poking fun, not trying to degrade.  My apologies, sincerely.

Comment: Your comment is clearly of no service to my question. Whether you like the way I write, or not, is not the subject at hand here..wouldnt you agree? Besides, I write like this all the time... Am i to think you are being discriminitive against my writting style? I certain follow stackflow etiquitte...

Comment: And I kept it clean, and easy to read. And I dont see anyone else complaining. I find it strange that you even took a moment out of your time to worry about my "lol-ing".. Is there not more important things in the world for you to worry for? Anyway, Im done..but unfortunately, still offended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow, where do I begin.  Ok, I fixed up your code.  Here's a list of the changes

1. Formatted code for legibility (you need some serious discipline here)
2. Sanitized inputs before using them in queries (prevents SQL injection)
3. Added string delimiters to associative array key lookups (prevents E_NOTICE errors)
4. Escaped potentially dangerous values before printing as HTML (prevents XSS)
5. Removed awkward `echo` statements and changed to HTML mode for large output strings instead
6. Updated javascript to use `$.post()` instead of `$.get()` since you read from the `$_POST` array at the top of the script.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['score'] ) )
{
    $result = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO score (score_count) VALUES (" . mysq_real_escape_string( $_POST['score'] ) . " )" );
    echo $result ? 'Vote Succeeded' : 'Vote Failed: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string( uid() );
$m = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_user_id1 = '$user_id' AND friend_status != '0' LIMIT 15" );

while ( $t = mysql_fetch_array( $m ) )
{
    $fid = mysql_real_escape_string( $t['friend_user_id2'] );
    $f = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_status != '' AND user_status_date != '0' AND user_id = '$fid' ORDER BY user_status_date ASC LIMIT 15" ) or die ( mysql_error() );

    while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array( $f ) )
    {
        $date = parse_date( $rows['user_status_date'] );
        ?>
        <div style="margin: 5px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="width:55px;">
                        <a href="page.php?id=<?php echo escapeForHtml( $rows['user_username'] ); ?>">
                            <?php _photo( $rows['user_id'] ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <a href="page.php?id=<?php echo escapeForHtml( $rows['user_username'] ); ?>" class="blue">
                            <b><?php echo escapeForHtml( $rows['user_username'] )?></b>
                        </a> - <span style="font-size:7pt;"><?php echo escapeForHtml( $date )?></span>
                        <span style="font-size:7pt;"> - <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateScore(this)" class="blue">Vote</a></span>
                        <br /><?php echo escapeForHtml( $rows['user_status'] ); ?></td><td valign="top">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }
}

function escapeForHtml( $value )
{
    return htmlspecialchars( $value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateScore(answer, correct)
{
    if (answer == correct)
    {
        $.post('index.php', {'score': '1'}, function(d)
        {
            alert('Vote Accepted: ' + d);
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

After I got all that done, I could then clearly see that your success condition for the POST to actually take place is unknown to me.  You compare `answer` to `correct` but this code snippet doesn't let me see where `correct` comes from.  Once inside the `updateScore()` function I can see that `answer` is a reference to the HTMLAnchorElement that was clicked - but what is the source for the value sent into `correct`?

To be specific, I'm taking about this bolded part here

onclick="updateScore(this, **correct**)"

### Edit!

Try this for a version of your function that updates the link after a successful vote

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateScore( answer )
{
    if ( confirm( "Are you sure?" ) )
    {
        $.post('index.php', {'score': '1'}, function(d)
        {
            alert('Vote Accepted: ' + d);
            $(answer).after("<span>You Voted!</span>").remove();
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this..my coding is terrible(lol). But im still learning, and am self-taught, so thanks for pointing all of that out. Ok, i copied this function from this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638147/updating-a-mysql-database-using-php-via-an-onclick-javascript-function/638219#638219

Comment: but what you say makes complete sense, now that i am looking over it. Could you suggest a solution of your own? Thanks sooooo much for your help:)

Comment: One of the other comments suggested using a checkbox, and hiding a submit buitton, but im abit confused about what they meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712355/pass-data-to-database-using-javascript-onclick/712456#712456

Comment: Well, don't try to get this done by just copy/pasting stuff willy-nilly. Other people's work is fine for examples and reference, but if you don't understand the fundamentals of whats going on, then you are doomed to many late nights.

Comment: Other than a button-click, do you know under what scenario you want the vote to be saved? To not be saved?

Comment: Ok.. I honestly am so brand new to javascript, I havent the slightest idea what i am doing. And because my php isnt completely upto scratch, trying to take on another language at this point is just too confusing for me. But you would be surprised with wat I have achieved, just copying and pasting.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I applied the changes you made..including the code you cleaned. But i am still getting nothing upon clicking the link.

Comment: You'll need to do a little more due-diligence before I can help you more. Are you getting a javascript error? If so, what's the error message? Is the onclick firing at all? (onclick="alert('test');"). If the click is firing, is your vote page failing? (use an HTTP sniffer like Firebug or Charles)

Comment: Ok, my apologies..thank you for being patient. There is nothing happening after I click the link. No error message. Yes, onclick fires perfectly. And i will need to do a browser restart to enable my firebug. So ill be back. Thanks again so much.

Comment: Ok. Firebug shows too errors upon onclick firing: correct is not defined
onclick(click clientX=577, clientY=318)WQgeIXGh...7xA%3D%3D (line 2)
[Break on this error] updateScore(this, correct); AND it outputs a syntax error where javascript(void); is used.

Comment: Ok, wonderful. That made the magic happen..lol. But I dont think it completes right through to posting the data. 1. I click the link, a dialog opens asking if im sure? 2. I click "yes", and another dialog opens and says "vote accepted:" and it shows the source of the page in the dialog...cont.

Comment: but there is so much source, that i cannot see the end of the dialog box, and am not sure if there is an extra confirmation? I do not see the "You voted!" alert either.

Comment: OK.. I just used the IE tab add-on to view the dialog minimized as it wouldnt minimize in FF properly, and the dialog had a final confirmation.."ok"..button. But nothing happened in the database.

Comment: Answer updated again.  I modified it to return custom output when the vote is POSTed.

Comment: Ok, that works! Thank you soo much!! I do get one error though: answer.after is not a function
Line 237
Also, there is a mispelt function in the posting code: (" . mysq_real_escape_string( $_POST['score'] )... but aside from that..all is working great!..

Comment: Oh ya - try $(answer).after instead

Comment: Yes!! That does it. I really can't express how thankful I am you answered my question. Youve taught me by helping me, & I won't quickly forget what Ive learned here with you. Gawd, I love this place, & its people like you that make it so great. Thanks so much Peter, & ill see you around hopefully:)

Comment: My pleasure.  For what it's worth, I'm self-educated too. So keep at it and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice, in your JavaScript code you are doing the Ajax request with `$.get`, and in your PHP code, you expect a POST variable `if(isset($_POST['score']))`.

So, if you use POST variables in the server side you should use [`$.post`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) in the client side.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I just changed it, so thats one issue down..lol. But Im still experiencing the same issue. However, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sanitizing your inputs. Anyone, using your app or not, could send you a "score", and you'll blithely put it in your database. Or they could as easily send you a SQL injection attack, by posting with score the string "1); some attack here ; insert into score(score_count) values ( 2";

Comment: Hi there. I understand sanitization of input, and considering that i only just coded this in less than an hour ago, alot still needs to be done, including sanitizing. But I will get to that once I actually have it working..and before it goes live to my website(its sitting locally on my pc).